# How can I populate a form using hierarchical JSON data

Tags: json, forms

I have a form that I need to populate with JSON data. The form contains select, textarea, and input elements that need to be populated. The JSON data is complex / hierarchical (i.e. many nested objects).

I am aware of http://www.keyframesandcode.com/code/development/javascript/jquery-populate-plugin/ but it uses square bracket notation to map to field names (e.g.

```
<input name="person[name][last]" ...
```

I need to use dot notation though (e.g.

```
<input name="person.name.last" ...
```

I'm using jQuery so a jQuery solution is fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hacked together alternative to populate using a recursive function:

```
function populator(json, nodes){
  $.each(json, function(key, value){
    newNodes = nodes ? nodes.slice() : [];
    newNodes.push(key);

    if (typeof(value)=="object") {
        populator(value, newNodes);
    else
        $('name["' + newNodes.join('.') + '"]').val(value);
    }
  });
}
```

With this you can do:

```
populator({
             person: {
                name: {
                   last: 'Doe', 
                   first: 'John'
                },
                address: {
                   street: '123 Main Street',
                   city: 'Montgomery',
                   state: 'AL'
             }
          });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BTW, what's the purpose of nodes.slice(). Doesn't slice with no arguments simply return the original array?

Comment: No, it returns a clone of the array.  The array needs to be cloned, because it can't be modified across iterations of nodes.

Comment: One thing, this won't work for multiple choice items (checkbox lists, multiple selects) as is.  It will need some tweaking to get that to work, basically a smart array handler.